# BSOD Debugging: Unexplained change in registry value

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-64, bsod

I have a crash dump from a BSOD which I'm trying to analyze.  WinDbg says it is a pool corruption but I'd like to dig a little deeper to improve my debugging skills.  These are the lines which lead to the crash:

```
fffff800`0300a998 498bf5          mov     rsi,r13
fffff800`0300a99b 8bee            mov     ebp,esi
fffff800`0300a99d 498b842400010000 mov     rax,qword ptr [r12+100h]
fffff800`0300a9a5 4885c0          test    rax,rax
fffff800`0300a9a8 0f8443030000    je      nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0x435 (fffff800`0300acf1)
fffff800`0300a9ae 498b942400010000 mov     rdx,qword ptr [r12+100h]
fffff800`0300a9b6 488bfa          mov     rdi,rdx
fffff800`0300a9b9 0f1f00          nop     dword ptr [rax]
fffff800`0300a9bc 4c8b02          mov     r8,qword ptr [rdx] ds:002b:fbfffa80`2d3db3a0=????????????????
```

The last line is causing the crash because it is trying to dereference the value of rdx which is holding an invalid memory address (fbfffa802d3db3a0 is not in canonical form).  But... how did this value become corrupted?  If I go up 3 lines, the address at r12+100h is being moved into rdx:

```
fffff800`0300a9ae 498b942400010000 mov     rdx,qword ptr [r12+100h]
```

This memory location holds a valid address:

```
0: kd> dq r12+100h l1 
fffff800`03065680  fffffa80`2f7c5870
```

In the next line rdx is being copied into rdi:

```
fffff800`0300a9b6 488bfa          mov     rdi,rdx
```

At this point, both registers should hold identical values.

The only other line between this one and the crash is:

```
fffff800`0300a9b9 0f1f00          nop     dword ptr [rax]
```

At the moment of the crash, rdi holds the correct address yet the address in rdx has become corrupted:

```
0: kd> .cxr fffff80000b90930
rax=fffffa8030f0a870 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffff80003065e50
rdx=fbfffa802d3db3a0 rsi=fffffa803f0c0000 rdi=fffffa802f7c5870
```

Can the NOP instruction cause the address to change in rdx? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The execution might have gotten to that instruction from somewhere else through a jump. It may be part of a loop, look further down for a jump back.

Comment: The fact that there's a NOP instruction before it strongly suggests that the instruction is a loop branch target as Jester suggests and the NOP was inserted to align the instruction for better performance.